# Buscar em todos os campos da tabela em uma Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, algoritmo-de-busca

Gostaria de saber qual a melhor forma de elaborar uma consulta que busca em todos os campos de uma tabela.

Digamos que possuo um site de notícias, e neste site tenho um `input` para `Search` em meu template. Ao digitar a informação neste template, ele necessita buscar em várias colunas na tabela, como título, descrição, autor, etc. Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Uma forma de fazer esta busca, é utilizando `IFs`, mas convenhamos que não é bom utilizar. E desta premissa que vem a minha dúvida.

Um exemplo seria:

```
    public ActionResult Buscar(string texto)
        {
            var titulo= AppService.ObterPorTitulo(texto);

            if (!titulo.Any())
            {
                var descricao= AppService.ObterPorDescricao(texto);

                if (!titulo.Any())
                {
                    var autor= AppService.ObterPorAutor(texto);
                        return View("index", autor);
                }
                return View("index", descricao);
            }
            return View("Index", titulo);
        }
```

Creio que isso seria uma [gambiarra](https://www.google.com.br/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=gambiarra%20programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o). Então vem a minha dúvida: Como buscar em todos os campos em uma única `Action`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse é um dos problemas clássicos da abordagem por *service*, que aí está inadequada para a solução. Ainda, se sua solução usa Entity Framework, que já implementa um repositório, fica mais inadequado ainda.

Em todo caso, como não sei o que você está usando, vou supor a abordagem por *service* mesmo.

O correto seria você fazer um método apenas que pesquise por tudo, por exemplo:

```
var noticia = AppService.Pesquisar(texto);
```

`Pesquisar` vai ter que ter uma chamada a uma sentença que pesquise conjuntamente em todos os campos desejados. No Entity Framework ficaria assim:

```
var noticia = contexto.Noticias
                      .FirstOrDefault(n => n.Titulo.Contains(texto) ||
                                           n.Descricao.Contains(texto) ||
                                           n.Autor.Nome.Contains(texto));
```

Por SQL ficaria assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM NOTICIAS N
INNER JOIN AUTOR A ON N.AUTORID = A.AUTORID
WHERE N.TITULO LIKE '%:TEXTO%'
OR N.DESCRICAO LIKE '%:TEXTO%'
OR A.NOME LIKE '%TEXTO%';
```

Comment: Não possuo um contexto para isso, mas tive esta dúvida, por isso postei somente este exemplo. Mas você conseguiu esclarecer minha dúvida. Obrigado!

Comment: Uma outra abordagem seria fazer o filtro no lado do cliente pensando na tela já com todos os dados carregados, utilizando a opção Filter do Angular.js: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: @JulioBorges Essa abordagem não é boa principalmente se o volume de notícias for muito grande. Seria preciso carregar a tabela toda em tela pra depois filtrar.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, realmente, pensando dessa forma não é o ideal. Vlw.