# Consultar em vários campos do registro em uma só consulta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework

Estou desenvolvendo um filtro de lista de itens, e gostaria de filtrar por qualquer termo do registro dos itens. Já vi isso funcionando no Angular, mas estou desenvolvendo para ASP.NET MVC 5 e utilizando o Entity Framework + Linq para as consultas.

Alguém já passou por isso?

Codigo que estou utilizando para atender a demanda:

```
List<Chamado> chamados = (from e in db.Chamado where e.StatusChamado != true select e).ToList();
        if(filtro != null)
        {
            chamados = chamados.Where(s => s.Id.ToString().Contains(filtro)
                                                       || s.Assunto.Contains(filtro)
                                                       || s.Descricao.Contains(filtro)
                                                       || s.ObraDestino.Descricao.Contains(filtro)
                                                       || s.ResponsavelChamado.Nome.Contains(filtro)).ToList();
        }
        return chamados;
```

Comment: Você precisa postar seu código com o problema/dúvida, se não fica difícil ajudar.

Comment: Você vai usar o Angular nas *Views* também?

Comment: vou postar o código sim @DontVoteMeDown

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, a principio não utilizarei o Angular

Comment: Veja se essa resposta lhe ajuda: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/60613/20615

Comment: Obrigado @Randrade!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está correta sua abordagem, mas eu faria diferente:

```
    var chamadosQuery = db.Chamado.Where(!e.StatusChamado);

    if(filtro != null)
    {
        chamadosQuery = chamadosQuery.Where(s => s.Id.ToString().Contains(filtro)
                                                   || s.Assunto.Contains(filtro)
                                                   || s.Descricao.Contains(filtro)
                                                   || s.ObraDestino.Descricao.Contains(filtro)
                                                   || s.ResponsavelChamado.Nome.Contains(filtro));
    }

    return chamados.ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez, pensei que teria alguma forma mais abstrata de efetuar isso, mas me atende perfeitamente.